# Expand all columns in power query (variable number of columns)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a data model in power query that generates some kind of **list of combinations**.

I created to some point the model but I have a step that I don't know how to do.

I need to expand all the columns named from 1 to a total number of rows  (the number of columns is variable). rows are from the source table

**Expand to new rows** I need, yes it will be a really long list that is what I want

The resulting table needs to be containing **3528 rows.**

*Important: expanding step by step is not acceptable because the number of columns will vary.*

[image: table]

```
let
Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("VYpLCoAwDETvknVhrKB7//9VkMaWXsPzG4oWXAyZlzch0IYdDiIQz3oEzpKhWkPRBGrQo8MMD2bWZ6W5k2mxYFIqv+mBVavNg0Fbken80fVSgvGnhH2W8QE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Custom.1 = _t, Custom = _t, variatie = _t]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Custom.1", type text}, {"Custom", Int64.Type}}),
#"Lowercased Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"variatie", Text.Lower, type text}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Lowercased Text", "Custom.2", each if [variatie] = "v" then [Custom.1] & "/" else [Custom.1]),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom.1", "variatie"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Custom.2", "Custom.1"}}),
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Custom.1", "Custom.1 - Copy"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Duplicated Column", {{"Custom.1 - Copy", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("/", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Custom.1 - Copy"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {"Custom", "Custom.1"}, {{"Count", each _, type table [Custom=nullable number, Custom.1=nullable text, #"Custom.1 - Copy"=nullable text]}}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom.2", each [Count][#"Custom.1 - Copy"]),
#"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom.1", "Count"}),
#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns2",{{"Custom.2", "Custom.1"}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns1",{"Custom"}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Index",{"Index", "Custom.1"}),
#"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Reordered Columns"),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true])
```

in
#"Promoted Headers"

[image: result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive function to get your output from your input.

I named this `fnExpandAll`

Enter this as a blank query and rename it:

```
(t as table, optional colNum as number) =>

let 
    colNames = Table.ColumnNames(t),
    Index = if colNum = null then  0 else colNum,
    expand = Table.ExpandListColumn(t, colNames{Index}),
    nextCol = Index+1,
    repeat = if nextCol < List.Count(colNames) then 
        fnExpandAll(expand, nextCol) else expand
in 
    repeat
```

You would then add these lines to the bottom of your posted code:

```
//...
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),

//add these lines

    expandAll = fnExpandAll(#"Promoted Headers")
in
    expandAll
```

[image]

**Edit:** *if, perchance, you want to expand each list, but not generate the extra rows as you show in your example result, you can simplify the custom function to:*

```
(t as table) =>

let 
    colNames = Table.ColumnNames(t),
    columns = List.Transform(Table.ToColumns(t), each List.Combine(_)),
    expand = Table.FromColumns(columns, colNames)
    
in 
    expand
```

[image]

Comment: Ron this worked like a charm, really pro stuff, I have a lot to learn.
Many thanks !!