# How to rearrange and create all possible combinations of a data with common cell, from multiple data entries in single column?

Tags: excel-formula, powerquery

I have a data set which I would like to reformat and create all possible combinations from the different data entries in a single column, which are linked together by another column which groups them. Another column also differentiates the data column. Easier to show a screen shot of an example.
[image: example data set here].

How can I do this in excel automatically using a formula or in power query if possible?

| Characteristic | Data | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| model | 1 series | bmw |
| model | 2 series | bmw |
| model | 3 series | bmw |
| model | 4 series | bmw |
| colour | blue | bmw |
| colour | white | bmw |
| model | a-class | mercedes |
| model | c-class | mercedes |
| model | e-class | mercedes |
| colour | black | mercedes |
| colour | silver | mercedes |

Comment: Please add your sample data as copiable text

Answer (score 3):

This is a methodology in powerquery. Within each group, works for any number of Characteristics and any number of Data per Characteristic

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

expand_all = (t as table, optional colNum as number) as table =>
    //stolen from Ron Rosenfeld https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69871922/expand-all-columns-in-power-query-variable-number-of-columns
    let  colNames = List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(t),{"Group"}),
    Index = if colNum = null then  0 else colNum,
    expand = Table.ExpandListColumn(t, colNames{Index}),
    nextCol = Index+1,
    repeat = if nextCol < List.Count(colNames) then   @expand_all(expand, nextCol) else expand
    in  repeat,

#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Group"}, {{"data", each 
      let  #"Grouped Rows2" = Table.Group(_, {"Characteristic"}, {{"data", each _[Data], type list }}),
      #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Grouped Rows2"),
      #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true])
      in #"Promoted Headers"
 , type table }}),
ColumnsToExpand = List.Distinct(Source[Characteristic]),
#"Expanded" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data",ColumnsToExpand ,ColumnsToExpand ),
ExpandLists=expand_all(#"Expanded")
in ExpandLists
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I had a manual way to do it but this is much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all data under the new heading "Model" has a hyphen in the second position.  You can use that to sort the old Data column.

Let's say the old Data column B, starting at row 3.
Using two empty parallel columns, I would enter the formulas:

(in one column):
=if(mid(B3,2,1)="-",B3,"x")

(in another column):
=if(mid(B3,2,1)<>"-",B3,"x")

Then drag those down.  Once you have the two lists, copy each one separately BUT right click and do a "Paste Special: Values only" in a temporary column.  You can hit the sort A-Z button (or Z-A sometimes) and sift it that way.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the hyphen? Only because I created this data from scratch and used cars as an example, the actual data set is a lot more complex and doesn't have a consistent format for "model". Model is actually server in my data and the server names are long-winded and do not have anything relating them.

Comment: you can use the length of the string, if it's long-winded?  You'll have to find something in common, or manually do a find-and-replace, if there aren't too many different common names.  You could also make a macro as find and replace, but the Excel I'm using (since 2003) locks macro-function into the exact cells, which requires manual shifting of data to accommodate the macro itself.

Comment: =if(len(B2)>10,"true","false")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

While I recommend using the power query method, this would be possible using formula in Office 365:

```
=LET(r,  A2:C12,
     c,  TAKE(r,,1),
     g,  TAKE(r,,-1),
     u,  UNIQUE(g),
     gm, DROP( REDUCE( 0, u,
               LAMBDA( x, y,
                      LET( m, UNIQUE(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(r,2),(g=y)*(c="model"))),
                      VSTACK(x,
                             HSTACK( EXPAND(y,ROWS(m),,y),
                                     m))))),
              1),
REDUCE( {"Group","Model","Colour"} ,SEQUENCE(ROWS(gm)),
LAMBDA( x,                          y,
       LET( clr, UNIQUE(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(r,2),(g=INDEX(gm,y,1))*(c="colour"))),
       VSTACK(x,
              HSTACK( EXPAND(INDEX(gm,y,1),ROWS(clr),,INDEX(gm,y,1)),
                      EXPAND(INDEX(gm,y,2),ROWS(clr),,INDEX(gm,y,2)),
                      clr))))))
```